# Finding duplicate model number in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that has almost 400,000 records.

I want to list out all the `Model_Number` which are duplicates

I tried with below 2 queries and the MySQL just keeps on loading and hangs.`AZ_Code' is the SKU

The query should return all records not one single record

```
select p1.AZ_Code from dumpdata as p1
join dumpdata as p2 on
(p1.`AZ_Code` != p2.`AZ_Code`)
group by p1.Model_Number
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT AZ_Code, Model_Number
FROM dumpdata
WHERE Model_Number IN (
    SELECT Model_Number
    FROM Dumpdata
    GROUP BY Model_number
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
)
```

Comment: Your second query should work. Just Change Dumpdata to dumpdata (Or reverse perhabs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the Duplicate model number you can use having count > 1

```
SELECT Model_Number
FROM dumpdata
group by model_number
having count(*) > 1
```